# Meta level repo that contains two git repos

Tags: git, vercel

We want to put two git repos and make them appear as one repo.  We use Vercel to deploy our site which takes in one repo, builds it, and serves it.

```
Repo 1: Demo App
Repo 2: Team, Contact, Etc
Meta App: Team, Contact, Etc + Demo App
```

We want to push the Demo app and make it available for people to download.  But we don't want to clutter it with everything else.

Is there a way to keep repos 1 and 2 separate but then make it appear as one to Vercel?

Comment: There might be a Vercel-specific answer, but there's no way to do this in Git: a repository cannot *contain* another repository. But there is a way to do something *very similar* in Git: a commit can *refer to a specific commit in another repository*, through what Git calls a *gitlink*. Pairing up the gitlink with a `.gitmodules` file entry forms what Git calls a *submodule*. A single "these are the pairs" repository, holding nothing but the `.gitmodules` file with the two submodule definitions plus the commits that give the other commit hash IDs, could work.

Comment: Note that many people who use submodules start calling them *sob*-modules because of the pain they induce. However, a single superproject consisting of *nothing but Gitlinks* should be as close to painless as you can get here, so for this particular case, if this were my own project, I would not object.